# How do I arrange these two-qubit states based on their entanglement?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

How can I arrange the following states in decreasing order based on their entanglement?

i) $\rho_1 = \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \langle0|\otimes  |+\rangle \langle+| +\frac{1}{2}|+\rangle \langle+|\otimes |1\rangle \langle1|$

ii) $\rho_2 = |\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$, where $|\psi\rangle=\sqrt{0.99}|00\rangle+0.1|11\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In decreasing order: $\rho_2$ then $\rho_1$, because no state is less entangled than a [separable state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_state) like $\rho_1$. We know that $\rho_1$ is separable, because it is a convex combination of product states.

On the other hand, $\rho_2$ is entangled because its [Schmidt rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) is $2$. Moreover, its density matrix

$$
\rho_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0.99 & & & 0.1\sqrt{0.99} \\
& & & \\
& & & \\
0.1\sqrt{0.99} & & & 0.01
\end{pmatrix}
$$

fails [Peres-Horodecki criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion), because

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.99 & & &  \\
& & 0.1\sqrt{0.99} & \\
& 0.1\sqrt{0.99}& & \\
& & & 0.01
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 
-0.1\sqrt{0.99}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$